# javascript mouseover while dragging

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop script and have hit the wall with one problem. When you take an item and start dragging it - the item is directly below your cursor and onmouseover event is very rarely fired on the items below. But i want other items to highlight when i drag something over them. One of the solutions would be not to drag anything at all - that way the mouse events would work, but that would look ugly. Has anyone ever done something like this and know how to overcome this problem?

If you're thinking about suggesting some JQuery plugin or something like that - please don't. I don't need a completed solution, this is educational.

Comment: Also, i know i can check while moving the mouse if i'm in bounds of an element and highlight that element, but that seems way too ... heavy if that's a correct word for it.

Comment: Are the elements you want to check if you're in bounds absolute?

Comment: Well, the solution should work universally on any element. It's not a problem to check the bounds, the problem is i don't want to specify which elements are "droppable", ideally i want the "dragOver" event that would fire on all elements being dragged over. But i guess the only solution these days is either having a "droppable" element list or looping through all the components.

Comment: this is basically bcoz of the fact that you already hold an element and not pointing to any other element, you can try one thing dont drag it just click it and get it focused then move your mouse, this may help..though not sure, it may change your functionality

Answer (score 2):

IMO, in order to have the `mouseover` event to be fired up frequently would be binding the `mouseover` event to the `parent` element of all the affected elements, or perhaps to the `document` itself, since events get bubbled up, they are probably the only elements that can fire the `mouseover` events.

Then further, write a `hit` method in your `mouseover` event and actively check the position of your mouse cursor, see whether it's going under the target element's boundary. Tradeoff in usability and performance. You choose.

My 2cents.

Or perhaps, you can reverse engineer `jQuery UI` to see how they implement the drag element. Haven't check thou, but I think there should be a wiser way.